# Resources to study Cubic Sequences and similar results

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, book-recommendation, online-resources

was reading an [article](https://www.radfordmathematics.com/algebra/sequences-series/difference-method-sequences/cubic-sequences.html) about general formula for $n^{th}$ term of a cubic sequence, and it mentioned the formula: $$u_n=an^3+bn^2+cn+d$$ Here, the values of $a, b, c$ & $d$ are calculated using the equations: $$6a=u_4-3u_3+3u_2-u_1,$$ $$12a+2b=u_3-2u_2+u_1,$$ $$7a+3b+c=u_2-u_1,$$ $$a+b+c+d=u_1$$

But there's no mention of the derivation of these equations calculating the values of $a, b, c, d.$

Now, such equations exist for linear, quadratic, cubic... so on for all higher degree sequences, but how are these equations derived?

I tried looking for derivation on YouTube, polynomial interpolation notes, numerical analysis books, but can't find any literature related to this.

Any book that covers this topic in detail?

Comment: Keyword : "LU method" for solving a parameterized linear system, generalizing Gauss triangularization method.

Comment: No...not looking for solution to system of linear equations, but how one arrives at these equations in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plainly take the definitions of $u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4$ by replacing $n$ with $1,2,3,4$ resp. :

$$\begin{cases}
u_1&=&a+b+c+d&(a)\\
u_2&=&8a+4b+2c+d&(b)\\
u_3&=&27a+9b+3c+d&(c)\\
u_4&=&64a+16b+4c+d&(d)
\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

Then, take (a) as it is, subtract (a) to (b) in order to obtain your second equation, then make the combination $(a)+(c)-2 \times (b)$ in order to get your third equation, etc.

**Remark 1** : Have you noticed that the coefficients in the RHS of your equations are :

$$\begin{array}{rrrr}1&-3&3&-1\\
&1&-2&1\\
&&1&-1\\
&&&1\end{array}\tag{2}$$

which are the binomial coefficients obtained in the development of $(a-b)^n$ ?

There is an explanation that necessitates to turn to matrix formulation.

This is connected to the so-called **LU decomposition** (L = lower triangular matrix, U = upper triangular matrix) of the coefficient matrix of system (1) above under the following reversed form :

$$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\
          1&2&4&8\\
          1&3&9&27\\
          1&4&16&64
\end{pmatrix}}_V=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}1&&&\\
          1&1&&\\
          1&2&1&\\
          1&3&3&1
\end{pmatrix}}_P\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\
          &1&3&7\\
          &&2&12\\
          &&&6\\
\end{pmatrix}}_Q$$

where $P$ is a so-called Pascal matrix,  $V$ a "Vandermonde" matrix, $Q$ being the matrix of coefficients you were given...

**Remark 2** : a different explanation for the presence of coefficients as given by (2), in direct connection with the reference you give, is that they are equivalent to **discrete derivatives** of order 3,2,1,0, resp. For example, the discrete "order 3" derivation of the 3rd degree polynomial $an^3+...$ with respect to variable $n$ is a constant equal to $(an^3)'''=6a$, the LHS of your first equation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. LHS of $(c)$ & $(d)$ in $(1)$ should be $u_3$, $u_4$. Back to original question, any book that covers this topic in detail? I'd like to study further on this topic.